# Spectral Theorem Multiplicationoperatorversion applied to a simple explicit example

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, normal-operator

At the moment I am trying to understand the following formulation of the spectral theorem better:

For a bounded, normal operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$, the pair $(H,T)$ is unitarily equivalent to $L^2((\Omega, \mu),M)$, where $\mu$ is a positive Baire measure on a locally compact space $\Omega$ and $M$ is the multiplication operator associated with a $\sigma(T)$-valued continuous function on $\Omega$.

I want to apply this theorem to an explicit finite dimensional example to understand it better. Now let T be a $2\times2$-matrix
\begin{align}
 T= \left(
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 2 \\ 
2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)\, .
\end{align}
$T$ is bounded and normal and the Hilbert space would be $\mathbb{R}^2$. According to the theorem this pair of $T$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is now unitarily equivalent to $L^2((\Omega, \mu),M)$. But I do not really know how to find out what $\mu$, $\Omega$ and $M$ are. How can I find out the right measure and the right space $\Omega$? Does the multiplication $M$ has something to do with the diagonal matrix?
I would be really geratful for any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess you notice first that your operator is unitarily equivalent to the diagonal one with eigenvalues $\pm 2$. So you should be able to take $\Omega =\{ 0, 1\}$, $\mu=\delta_0+\delta_1$ (point measures at $0$, respectively $1$) and $M$ is the multiplication operator with $-2$, respectively $2$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you very much, that makes sense. What I don't really understand is how the $L^2$-space then looks like.. Is there a way to see how $L^2((\{0,1\}, \delta_0+\delta_1),M)$ what is?

Comment: It contains functions from $\{0,1\} $ to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. this are just tuples of two real numbers (aka $\mathbb{R}^2$). Now what does the scalar product look like? We have $$\langle f, g\rangle = \int f(x) g(x) (\delta_0(x) +\delta_1(x)) = f(0) g(0) + f(1)g(1).$$ If we write our functions as tuples, i.e. $f=(x_1, x_2), g=(y_1, y_2)$, then the above becomes $$\langle (x_1,x_2), (y_1, y_2)\rangle = x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2.$$ Thus, we recover the usual euclidean scalar product. Now what is the action of $M$? We said it is a multiplication operator with $(Mf)(x)=M(x)f(x)$ where $M(0)=2, M(1)=-2$.

Comment: Then we have with our tuple notation $$M(x_1,x_2)=(2x_1, -2x_2),$$ meaning we recover our original diagonal operator. I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven It helps a lot! Thank you! :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven If I may ask you just one more thing... This example is completely real. How do $\Omega$ and $\mu$ change if I would have an normal matrix like $[[0,1],[-1,0]]$ with complex eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$?

Comment: Are you considering it as a real or as a complex Hilbert space?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven as a complex Hilbert space

Comment: Then you end up with the very same construction above. First you diagonalize and then rewrite $\mathbb{C}^2$ as $L^2$ with the sum of two dirac deltas.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven perfect, thank you so much!!